# How to Initialize, assign and return a string array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm trying to fit the below code in one of my projects. But it throws an error while assigning string to an array. Can you please tell me what did I do wrong?

```
Public string[] ReturnStringArray()
{
   string[] sArray = new string[]{};
   try
   {    
      string str1 = "hi";
      string str2 = "this";
      string str3 = "is";
      string str4 = "sample array";
      sArray = {str1 , str2 , str3 , str4} //There is an error here
   }
   catch { throw new exception; }
   return sArray;
}
```

Comment: And then we ask "what does the error say"?

Answer (score 2):

You declare the value of the array like this:

```
string[] sArray = new string[5]; //Declare its length number
sArray[0] = "hi"  // or sArray[0] = str1
```

Or you can also do this:

```
string[] sArray = new string[] {"hi", "hello", "foo};
```

Or you can also do this:

```
string str1 = "hi";
string str2 = "this";
string str3 = "is";
string str4 = "sample array";
string[] sArray = {str1, str2, str3, str4};
```

Answer (score 1):

add strings to a string list and convert the final string list to an array

```
        public string[] ReturnStringArray()
        {

        List<string> slist = new List<string>();

        string str1 = "hi";
        string str2 = "this";
        string str3 = "is";
        string str4 = "sample array";

        slist.Add(str1);
        slist.Add(str2);
        slist.Add(str3);
        slist.Add(str4);

        return slist.ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays has not support to add like this. First of all you need to set arrays max length before fill indexes...

Maybe can use `List<string>` and returns. After then still need string array you will use `List.ToArray()`.

Answer (score -1):

please find changes on following, you have add items to array at once like this

```
public string[] ReturnStringArray()
{
    string[] sArray;
    try
    {
        string str1 = "hi";
        string str2 = "this";
        string str3 = "is";
        string str4 = "sample array";
        sArray = new string[] { str1, str2, str3, str4 };
    }
    catch(Exception e) { throw e; }
    return sArray;
}
```